# How can I fix the sound in my iPhone app for iPhone OS 2.2?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

The sound for my iPhone app worked fine when I was running iPhone OS 2.0.  I updated to OS 2.2 and now the sound only works with headphones.  How can I make the sounds work for both headphones and the speaker again?

Comment: it's not programming question. Try to ask at superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try toggling the Ring/Silent switch above the volume control on the left side of the unit.